# Concatenating column objects, zeros missing

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate two columns - an hour (hh) and minute (mm) column. Some values are double zeros. When I concatenate the hour and minute columns, the hour column is not included. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
import datetime as dt

url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h2014.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/"
data_csv = urlopen(url)
df = pd.read_csv(data_csv, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

#Reset Index + remove first row + rename column
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[1:]
df = df.rename(columns={'#YY': 'YY'})

df['Time'] = df[df.columns[3:5]].apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
Out[203]: 
1          0:0
2         0:20
3         0:40
4          1:0
5         1:20
```

**Should be:**

```
Out[203]: 
1         00:00
2         00:20
3         00:40
4         01:00
5         01:20
```

Comment: `df.columns[4:5]` only give you one column.  Try `[3:5]` or `[4:6]` instead.

Comment: You are correct, 3:5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.cat` without need to use `apply`

```
df[df.columns[4]].str.cat(df[df.columns[5]], sep=':')
```